# Cloud Bitbucket Can I use the self-hosted runner docker image as a base and augment it?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

NOTE:  I'm an embedded programmer, so devops stuff is mildly mysterious to me and I might be using the wrong terms.

When creating my BitBucket self hosted runners, do I HAVE to use docker in docker, or can I take the self-hosted runner container image and add my required tools and licenses to it?

i.e. the docker command it gives me when I create a self-hosted runner has this in it:  `docker-public.packages.atlassian.com/sox/atlassian/bitbucket-pipelines-runner`, can I just create my own Dockerfile image which uses that, and add my software packages, environment variables, etc. and invoke that instead of the original one?

Or do I necessarily need to do docker-in-docker?

As I mentioned in the beginning, a lot of the devops stuff is just what google/stackexchange tells me to do and thus vaguely cargo-cultish.  Getting credentials and other stuff from the self-hosted runner image into my docker-in-docker image (without building credentials into the image) seems like its more work to me.

Thanks for any insight